# Installing MarkLogic-RHEL7-8.0-8.x86_64.rpm on RHEL7. AdminUI not coming up

Tags: marklogic

We are installing MarkLogic version 8.0-8 on our RHEL7 testbox. Installation was successful and we are also able to start the service as root. But when we are trying to access the adminUI,  we are getting the message as "This site can't be reached testbox02 took too long to respond. We checked the ErrorlLogs.txt and we are not able to find any specific errors. We are just having info level messages and only one warning level message i.e Warning: Metering database is not configured - Temporarily disabling usage metering

Below are the log entries :-

```
2018-03-20 12:28:43.624 Notice: Starting MarkLogic Server 8.0-8 x86_64 in /opt/MarkLogic with data in /var/opt/MarkLogic  
2018-03-20 12:28:43.624 Info: MarkLogic Converters 8.0-8 found  
2018-03-20 12:28:43.635 Info: Host testbox02.local running Linux 3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo))  
2018-03-20 12:28:43.662 Info: SSL FIPS mode has been enabled  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.585 Info: Native plugin cache manifest initialized  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.588 Info: Started MarkLogic Server {securityVersion=80008,software-version=8000800,effective-version=8000800}
2018-03-20 12:28:44.589 Info: Forest Schemas state changed from unmounted to mounted  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.590 Info: Mounted forest Schemas locally on /var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests/Schemas read write  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.590 Info: Forest Schemas state changed from mounted to recovering  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.591 Info: Forest Schemas forgetting previous master 14836081943655974042 because configured master changed  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.592 Info: Forest Security state changed from unmounted to mounted  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.592 Info: Mounted forest Security locally on /var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests/Security read write  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.592 Info: Forest Documents state changed from unmounted to mounted  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.593 Info: Mounted forest Documents locally on /var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests/Documents read write  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.593 Info: Forest Documents state changed from mounted to recovering  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.593 Info: Forest Security state changed from mounted to recovering  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.593 Info: Forest Security forgetting previous master 7315667923233664693 because configured master changed
2018-03-20 12:28:44.593 Info: Forest Documents forgetting previous master 11151632178160615129 because configured master changed
2018-03-20 12:28:44.595 Info: Forest Modules state changed from unmounted to mounted  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.595 Info: Mounted forest Modules locally on /var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests/Modules read write  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.595 Info: Forest Modules state changed from mounted to recovering  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.597 Info: Forest Modules forgetting previous master 10229848459304948380 because configured master changed
2018-03-20 12:28:44.597 Info: Forest Extensions state changed from unmounted to mounted  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.597 Info: Mounted forest Extensions locally on /var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests/Extensions read write  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.597 Info: Forest Extensions state changed from mounted to recovering    
2018-03-20 12:28:44.597 Info: Forest Schemas state changed from recovering to open  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.598 Info: Forest Extensions forgetting previous master 1555166925840436669 because configured master changed
2018-03-20 12:28:44.599 Info: Forest Last-Login state changed from unmounted to mounted  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.599 Info: Mounted forest Last-Login locally on /var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests/Last-Login read write  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.599 Info: Forest Last-Login state changed from mounted to recovering  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.599 Info: Forest Documents state changed from recovering to open  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.600 Info: Forest Security state changed from recovering to open  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.601 Info: Forest Last-Login forgetting previous master 6465312311369396867 because configured master changed
2018-03-20 12:28:44.601 Info: Forest Triggers state changed from unmounted to mounted  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.601 Info: Mounted forest Triggers locally on /var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests/Triggers read write  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.601 Info: Forest Triggers state changed from mounted to recovering
2018-03-20 12:28:44.601 Info: Forest Triggers forgetting previous master 16473938086058275643 because configured master changed
2018-03-20 12:28:44.602   Warning: Metering database is not configured - Temporarily disabling usage metering
2018-03-20 12:28:44.602 Info: Database Documents is online with 1 forest  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.603 Info: Database Triggers is online with 1 forest  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.603 Info: Forest Fab state changed from unmounted to mounted
2018-03-20 12:28:44.603 Info: Mounted forest Fab locally on  
 /var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests/Fab read write  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.603 Info: Forest Fab state changed from mounted to recovering  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.603 Info: Forest Fab forgetting previous master 1822526007971900908 because configured master changed  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.604 Info: Database Schemas is online with 1 forest  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.604 Info: Forest Meters state changed from unmounted to mounted    
2018-03-20 12:28:44.604 Info: Mounted forest Meters locally on /var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests/Meters read write  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.605 Info: Database Security is online with 1 forest  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.606 Info: Forest Meters state changed from mounted to recovering  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.606 Info: Forest Meters forgetting previous master 11134717009093972564 because configured master changed  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.606 Info: Database Meters is online with 1 forest  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.608 Info: Forest App-Services state changed from unmounted to mounted  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.608 Info: Mounted forest App-Services locally on /var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests/App-Services read write  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.609 Info: Forest App-Services state changed from mounted to recovering  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.609 Info: Forest App-Services forgetting previous master 10768336816706261141 because configured master changed  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.637 Info: Forest Modules state changed from recovering to open  
2018-03-20 12:28:44.639 Info: Forest Extensions state changed from recovering to open
```

We did try to check with curl and we are seeing below error:-

```
[root@testbox02 Logs]# curl -I http://XX.XXX.XX.XXX:8001/   
HTTP/1.1 302 Found  
X-Frame-Options: DENY  
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; media-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';  
X-Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; media-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';  
Location: initialize-admin.xqy  
Server: MarkLogic  
Content-Length: 0  
Connection: Keep-Alive  
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
```

Can anyone help or suggest if we are doing something wrong?Is it related to X-Frame-Options: DENY?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: It looks like it tries to redirect to the init-admin page, but fails at that. Are you entitled to support? Best to reach out to them..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this an initial install ?  errors indicate that there was a previously installed configuration found.
If an install (vs upgrade) is intended then make sure /var/opt/MarkLogic is empty before installing or it will attempt (and fail hopefully) to join the pre-configured cluster.  This appears to be that.

If this is an upgrade something more severe is amis -- is this a VM, Docker, cloud system ? or is. /var/opt/MarkLogic possibly a remote mount or shared SAN or NAS storage ? 
check /var/log/messages for more details on the early startup process for clues.

Comment: Thanks all for your help. We are able to resolve the problem. Our network team has disabled the IP Firewall and we are able to access the adminUI page. Previously IP Firewall was enabled. The problem was at OS level.

Comment: @Mpathak for the benefit of others, would you mind putting your response in an answer and marking it "Accepted"?

Comment: Hello Dave, we have forwarded the issue to Unix team and they have done something at OS level. I am not clear about about what they did, but as the last email from unix team, I see, they have changed some firewall configuration in unix box.

Comment: I will update here once I know the exact steps or configuration changes they have performed